# 最小値のインデックスを求めたい

Tags: python

この問題がわからず困っています。

## 問題文

配列のst番目から最後の要素までの、最小値を探す。ただし、最小値の値そのものではなく、インデックスを求める。(何番目が最小値であるかを返す)下記の[ここを書く]にコードを入力せよ。

```
def min_index(a,st):
  minidx=st # 先頭の要素のインデックスを最小値のインデックスとする
  for i in range(st+1,len(a)) # i番目のほうが最小値よりも小さいなら
    if[ここを書く]: # iを最小値のインデックスをする
      minidx = i
  return[ここを書く]
```

先ほど挙げた実行例は別のプログラムでした、すみません！
この問題の実行例は載っていませんでした。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　この問題について、どんなことを思いつかれましたか？　上手く動かなかったプログラムか、考えたことのリストを「編集」から追記していただけませんでしょうか？　そうすることで、より適切な回答ができそうです。

Comment: 「問題文」では最小値のインデックスを求めるなのに、実行例では配列全体のソート結果を表示しており、説明が食い違っています。

Answer (score 4):

このタイプの書き方は「最初から最後までの要素を順番にひとつずつ、記録を更新しながら見ていく」というパターンです。

リスト `[a, b, c, ..., d, e]` の要素の中でどれが一番小さい値なのか知りたいとき、もし `[a, b, c, ..., d]` までの中でどこが一番小さいのかが分かっていれば、そこの値と `e` とをたった 1 回比べるだけで最小値を求めることができます。わざわざ他の全ての要素 `a, b, c, ..., d` に対して `e` と比べる必要はありません。

更に、`[a, b, c, ..., d]` の中で一番小さい値も、同じようにして「それまでの最小値」と `d` を比べれば分かります。これを繰り返すと、まずは `a` と `b` のどっちが小さいか調べて、小さい方と `c` とでどっちが小さいか調べて、……としていけば良いことが分かります。

今回のプログラムでは、このようにして最小値（のインデックス）を求めています。

まず、次のように `for` 文を書いて繰り返すことで、要素を最初から順番に見ています。

```py
for i in range(st+1, len(a)):
```

次のこの部分では、「それまでの最小値」と「今見ている要素」のどちらが小さいかを調べます。

```py
if [ここを書く]:
```

最後に、もし「今見ている要素」の方が小さいのであれば、その要素のインデックスを覚えておきます。

```py
minidx = i
```

この動作を最後まで行えば、`minidx` に最小値のインデックスが代入されているはずです。ですので、これをそのまま返せば良いです。

```py
return [ここを書く]
```

以上をまとめるとプログラムが書けます。念の為、完全に動作するプログラムを [Wandbox に置いておきました](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kxfsVDwGz0oJFelP)ので、こちらも必要であればご覧ください。

Answer (score 1):

問題文は「配列aのst番目から最後の要素」という事だと思います。
また、for文の文末には:が必要です。

```
def min_index(a,st):
  minidx=st # 先頭の要素のインデックスを最小値のインデックスとする
  for i in range(st+1,len(a)): # i番目のほうが最小値よりも小さいなら
    if a[i] < a[minidx]: # iを最小値のインデックスをする
      minidx = i
  return minidx
```

Answer (score 0):

宿題なら、多分違う書き方してほしいんだろうが、pythonを使えば、このように楽に取得できます：

```
def get_min_index(items, start_index):
    min_value = min(items[start_index: ])
    min_value_index = start_index + items[start_index: ].index(min_value)
    return min_value_index

samples = [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5, 9, 3]
result_index = get_min_index(samples, 6)

print(f'index={result_index}, value={samples[result_index]}')
```

> index=6, value=3